# Difference between Play Framework 1.2.5.1 and 1.2.6 release?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

What is the difference between Play Framework 1.2.5.1 and 1.2.6 ?  It seems both been released after detection of vulnerable session handling issue. 
http://www.playframework.com/security/vulnerability/20130806-SessionInjection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compared to 1.2.5, version 1.2.5.1 has only changed the cookie handling, resolving the vulnerability you mentioned. [You can see in the diff](https://github.com/playframework/play1/compare/1.2.5...1.2.5.1) that only 3 files were changed, all related to this issue.

Play 1.2.6 however [contains all the changes since the release of 1.2.5](https://github.com/playframework/play1/compare/1.2.5...1.2.6) last year. Most of the changes (maybe all, I did not read the commit logs and corresponding issues in detail) seem to pertain to non-critical bugfixes.

Comment: Why don't just suggest everyone to update to "all updates/fixes applied" 1.2.6 version? Don't fully understand this releasing logic Play Framework team does still use

Answer (score 2):

See the commits between these versions:

- [1.2.5...1.2.5.1](https://github.com/playframework/play1/compare/1.2.5...1.2.5.1)
- [1.2.5...1.2.6](https://github.com/playframework/play1/compare/1.2.5...1.2.6)