# Difference between Play Framework 1.2.5.3 and 1.2.7

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm doing a new install on a workstation and notice there is now a split in Play 1.x as there is 1.2.5.3 and 1.2.7. It's somewhat hard to find the differences through searching. I poked around in the source here

https://github.com/playframework/play1/tree/1.2.7

and don't really see any reason to use 1.2.5.3 instead of 1.2.7 (most of my code was developed in 1.2.5 but the update in production didn't break anything). Any reason to use 1.2.5.3 because it's "newer". I know these 1.x guys are limited in their time and working hard on 1.3 so if anyone just has a quick answer, it would be helpful, I think.

This was also asked before with 1.2.6, I expect the same might be true for 1.2.7 then.

[Difference between Play Framework 1.2.5.1 and 1.2.6 release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228420/difference-between-play-framework-1-2-5-1-and-1-2-6-release)

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Play Framework 1.2.5.1 and 1.2.6 release?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228420/difference-between-play-framework-1-2-5-1-and-1-2-6-release)

Comment: Unnecesarily confusing in my opinion, why don't they just apply all updates to one version in the 1.x branch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.2.5.3 adds a new version of the netty library (3.4.2 -> 3.5.11).

Recently, 1.2.5.1 was released with just a security fix and 1.2.6 with all fixes sinces 1.2.5. Same for 1.2.5.2 and 1.2.7.

Since then, the 1.2.5.3 was released with only the netty upgrade. There wasn't a 1.2.8 releases with that containing all other fixes. You should check the issue Carsten mentioned to check the commits on both versions to make sure you've got what you need with 1.2.7 because as far as I can see, the netty upgrade is not yet in 1.2.7